# How to Check Angular current route without hard-coded?

Tags: angular6, angular5

I want to check url

```
 private m_Router: Router

if(this.m_Router.url == "create/xxx")
{
.....
}
```

I could achieve checking url and take action based on URL well with code above. But I have implemented this hard-coded.

May I take path from Router ?

I can not use  private a_Router: ActivatedRoute
because it is not related with url.

The main problem is that when I am in create/xxx page, when I try to navigate create/xxx/yyy url, the component that has url create/xxx , is triggered again(ngOnInıt) so I want to check in   ngOnInit() if this is a url that really belong to this page. I mean how can I read PATH variable from Router ?

Comment: use var pathname = window.location.pathname;
console.log(pathname);

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(private router: Router ) {
```

}

**Then call it's URL parameter:

**

```
console.log(this.router.url)
    if(this.router.url==""){
}
```

Comment: No I did not mean this. I ve already coded like this way. I asked I mean how can I read PATH variable from Router so that we would not write hard- coded but your code includes hard-coded url too.